# Are methods called from a separate thread, run on the calling thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

I've been using threads for 2-3 days now, and I've got a quick question regarding methods. I'm making an Android application and it starts off with the main UI thread (let's call it the "UI Thread" for clarity). I'm spawning a new thread using the following code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        someMethod();
    }

});
thread.start();
```

My question is, will `someMethod()` also run on the new thread that I just created because I'm calling it from there? Or will it run on the UI thread? For reference, `someMethod()` is located outside outside of the method that's creating the new thread.

If `someMethod()` won't run on the new thread, how do I make it do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> will someMethod() also run on the new thread that I just created because I'm calling it from there?

Yes, that is exactly what happens. The method is just code. It's independent of the thread-of-control that happens to be running in it at a given point and time. This also means that there could be multiple threads executing that code at any given point in time if there are multiple cpu/cores.

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept your answer once I'm able to do so (SO wants me to wait another 12 minutes).

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know there was a wait period. BTW, you should give yourself a real username. ;-)

Comment: The wait period is probably because I don't have enough points. One more question... would your answer be the same if I replaced the method with an interface? For example, instead of calling "someMethod()", I set an interface to an object like so: "mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);", where "onCompletionListener" is an interface. Thanks again!

Comment: If you refer to an object based on it's class or superclass or interface it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at `Callable<V>` and `Future<T>`, there you can call methods, that are **not** processed on the calling thread. You shouldn't work with threads anyway nowadays.
There are more modern approaches available.

Here is a link that should give you an idea http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#futures

Answer (score 1):

All of the actions taken by `run`, including calling `someMethod`, stay on the new `Thread` unless that code tells Java to run something in another thread (like with `invokeLater` or by using an `Executor`).